# m2e vs wtp vs m2e-wtp?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have some idea about m2e and wtp but could not figure out what extra m2e-wtp provides on top of m2e and m2e-wtp ?

**My understanding :-**

`m2e :-` m2e connector helps to import and create maven projects under eclipse where you can build the project with in eclipse also. There are various companies like

m2e
m2eEclipse
SonarQube m2e connector

`WTP:-` Web Tools Project adds on various j2ee capabilities like Web Server Tools(WST) which helps to create server with in eclipse and helps
in hot code replacement(My guess it picks up the pom setting and accordingly publish it under right directory of server. I am not sure who among wtp or m2e-wtp does it ?)

`m2e-wtp :-` I am not sure what extra m2e-wtp provides on top of m2e and m2e-wtp and how does it help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained on the [m2e-wtp website](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/):

> The Maven Integration for WTP project, also known as m2e-wtp, aims at
>   providing a tight integration between Maven Integration for Eclipse
>   (a.k.a m2e) and the Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP).
>
> m2e-wtp provides a set of m2e connectors used for the configuration of
>   Java EE projects in WTP, brings unique Maven features to your Eclipse
>   IDE and helps you convert your Eclipse projects to Maven.

So m2e provides 'basic' Maven integration in Eclipse (Java Configuration, pom.xml editor,  and other APIs for other 3rd party plugins). WTP provide a way to configure Java EE projects for deployments to a range of application servers, as well as other JavaEE related tools and validation, but it has no knowledge of Maven.

m2e-wtp is the bridge between m2e and WTP (see the clever logo?). It basically adds the relevant WTP's Java EE Facets to war, ear projects, based on the informations found in pom.xml, and configures them so that WTP can deploy them properly onto application servers.